# How to fetch using specific date from timestamp column in Criteriaquery?

Tags: java, spring, timestamp, criteriaquery

I have a **timestamp** column in database and want to query date like this **2023-07-27**,
Here is my snippet:

```
   List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
              SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date start_date = dateFormat.parse(startDate);
                if (request.getKey().equals("createdAt")) {
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("createdAt"),start_date);
                }
```

I cannot get value based on specific date for date range it works please help.

Comment: Thank you i get my answer.predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.function(
                    "date", Date.class,
                    root.get("createdAt")),start_date));